Design of Elastic Serilog Centralized logging solution - multiple components
We have the following components in place for our system. All are built using .net (core 2 and .net 4.6.1).

A - .netcore 2 web app deployed as an AppService
B - .net 4.6.1 desktop app acting as an Manager for Workers deployed on a Windows
VM (Azure) / there are multiple instances of B (multi-tenant)
C...N - a number of workers (.net 4.6.1) each one deployed on a Windows VM (Azure)

We need to implement centralized logging so that we gather and interpret logs from all components. We started creating a PoC with ELK deployed in Cloud (Azure hosted) together with Serilog Sinks.
If all components would have access to the internet, then this would be simple, but we do have some constraints:

Workers C...N - have access only to B. They don't have access to the internet.
Component of type B has access only to A; they also don't have access to the internet.

Here is our plan:


Component A - has an Elastic Sink configured to access ELK cloud instance and an API point receiving logs from all other components;
Components C...N - have a Serilog Http Sink and a Elastic Common Schema Logs Formatter and are sending their logs to B.
Components B - have a Serilog Http Sink and Elastic Common Schema Logs Formatter sending their logs to A and a redirect rule for the logs sent by C...N.

Where is the challenge? The API endpoint where we need to send the Logs coming from components B...N to ELK. The logs need to keep the original properties (ECS schema). Our options:

API call to ELK instance sending the logs. Disadvantages: need secondary auth, need to detect on which index/datastream to send the logs.
new Serilog context with CustomTextFormater. The CustomTextFormater will just return the incoming logs. This way we could write _logger.LogJsonPayload(payload) and all the logs are sent via existing Serilog Elastic sink. This seems hacky, but I think it will do the job.

What do you think about these options? Can you think of others?
